# Is a distribution whose mean and variance are its only non-zero cumulants neccesarily Gaussian?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, cumulants

I have a distribution. Its cumulants are all zero except for its mean and variance. Does that necessarily mean that my distribution is Gaussian?

Or in other words, are there non-Gaussian distributions whose only non-zero cumulants are mean and variance.

Comment: The only distribution having finitely many non-zero cumulants (let alone two non-zero cumulants) is the Gaussian distribution, as has been shown by Marcinkiewicz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since one can analytically reconstruct the distribution given all its cumulants, the answer is that a distribution with any mean, any non-zero variance, and all other cumulants zero is necessarily a Gaussian.

A stronger, and non-trivial, statement is that the cumulant generating function cannot be a finite polynomial of degree greater than 2; thus there is no distribution with any mean, any non-zero variance, and any non-zero skew but no non-zero higher cumulants.

Comment: If one uses moments instead of cumulants, then the answer to question depends on whether the distribution lives on a bounded or unbounded interval. Is this different for cumulants?